# How to copy/clone econml estimator?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Is there a way to clone an `econml` estimator? For `sklearn` there is the `clone` function:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.base import clone

est = LinearRegression()
est2 = clone(est)

est is est2 # False
```

Is there something similar for `econml`? (If not how hard would it be to build this?)

```
from econml import LinearDRLearner

est = LinearDRLearner()
est2 = econml_clone(est) # does this exist?
```

Ps: should there be an econml tag?

Comment: You can have multiple variables with the class `LinearRegression()`... `a = LinearRegression()`, and `b = LinearRegression()`
Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Not really. I understand how to make multiple instances of the same class. However when passing instances through functions it's often useful to be able to take a copy without changing the original estimator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perhaps use `est2 = copy.deepcopy(est)` from the copy module?